# mysql structure double unique

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a mysql table and have got stuck with making it.

2 columns required:

```
aid
bid
```

The trick is aid is not unique and bid is not unique, but the combination of aid-bid IS unique.

EG:

```
a b ok?
0 1 y
0 2 y
0 7 y
1 1 y
1 7 y
8 3 y
0 7 N - since 0 7 is already in table...
```

How can I make this table in sql so it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
create table my_table (
a int,
b int,
unique key (a,b) );
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to create a unique index for those columns:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX id_index ON mytable (aid,bid);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add a unique constraint to the table

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD UNIQUE KEY (aid, bid);
```

Then change your code to trap the exception when you try to insert a duplicate key.